# What's up with the Gyro Pilot in Road Warrior and the pilot in Beyond Thunderdome?

Tags: post-apocalyptic

Bruce Spence appears in both the Road Warrior and Beyond Thunderdome as (apparently) the same character, a post-apocalyptic bush pilot. I say apparently, because I found [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089530/trivia) on IMDB:

> Bruce Spence, who played the Gyro Captain in Mad Max 2 plays Jedediah,
>   a different character who robs Max at the start of the film.
>   Confusingly, both characters use flying machines (in Mad Max 2 it was
>   a 'Gyrocopter', in Mad Max 3 a Transavia PL-12 'Airtruk') and little
>   is done to differentiate the two different characters.

A different character? Who flies aircraft (in a decidely non-aircraft situation) in both movies? Portrayed by a very descript (the opposite of non-descript) actor? It seems easy enough to dismiss, but there is some secondary confirmation that this is supposed to be a different character on some other sites.

To add to the mix, there is the theory that Bruce Spence's character in Thunderdome is supposed to be

> the co-pilot who left the children to go for help.

It sounds like maybe the character developed differently between script and production...does anybody know the whole story?

Comment: "teotwawki" isn't exactly a useful, or really necessary, tag. "post-apocalyptic" may be a better way to go if such a tag is needed.

Comment: I'm not really clear on just what you are asking.  You've piqued my curiosity about what is going on, but I'm still a bit confused about just what the question is.

Comment: I guess it's more of a "behind the scenes" than in-universe question...is the intention of the writer/director that they are the same character, or are they unrelated, or what? I would say that because of the nature of the credit in "Road Warrior", "The Gyro Captain", it's POSSIBLE that they're the same character...but there's this confusion in secondary sources.

Comment: The persons responsible for writing the credits have been sacked.

Comment: The credits have been redone at the last minute at great expense.

Comment: I can't answer, but I can point you to: madmaxmovies.com/flubs/othertrivia.html

Comment: Updated link: http://www.madmaxmovies.com/mad-max-2-the-road-warrior/cast-and-crew/bruce-spence/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I owned the Thunderdome magazine issue that came out when the movie released.  It also mentioned that the characters were not intended to be the same, but similar.

[Magazine image](http://www.mycomicshop.com/search?TID=419891)

Answer (score 4):

Well, I just watched the four movies in a role, and came to notice something that seems pretty overlooked on these forums: Max is mad. So I would assume that in the same way that his mind plays several tricks with him during the course of Fury Road, i would say he just ran into a random fellow with flying capability and attached a face who would make sense to him, the only other guy who also owns a flying machine.

Answer (score 2):

I had just assumed that they are the same character. Given the gyro captain's personality in Road Warrior I had just thought that he had a child with the girl he was with and either just up and left her and the tribe for whatever reasons like parents do or simply fled when things got tough. I figured some time had passed between Road Warrior and Thunderdome and though Max and Jebediah may know each other a bit, it is an apocalyptic time when its every man for himself and times get harder and harder. I'm in no way saying that's it, but that's what I just always thought.